# When I imported these characters they looked like this. But they are supposed to look like a Roblox character

Tags: materials, import

When I imported these characters they looked like this. But they are supposed to look like a Roblox character

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This looks a UV problem. I would recommend going into your UV editing tab and checking to see if your textures are projected on the right spot. if they are and it is still acting up I recommend looking in you'r Shader editor for any problems. but this should be fixed with some work with your UVs.

**edit**: Your question is also poorly worded so I cannot tell if this is something to do with Textures or shading with materials.